# Position element below sibling element that uses absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I have an element with the class `slide-bottom` that is positioned underneath other content in the parent `.container` div using `z-index`. I used `position: absolute` on `.slide-bottom` so the element slides in underneath the other content. Within the parent div, I also have a `nav` element that I would like to be positioned below the `.slide-bottom` content during and after the animation. How can I do this?

```css
.slide-bottom {
  -webkit-animation: slide-bottom 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
  animation: slide-bottom 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}


/* ----------------------------------------------
 * Generated by Animista on 2020-2-3 14:56:40
 * Licensed under FreeBSD License.
 * See http://animista.net/license for more info. 
 * w: http://animista.net, t: @cssanimista
 * ---------------------------------------------- */


/**
 * ----------------------------------------
 * animation slide-bottom
 * ----------------------------------------
 */

@-webkit-keyframes slide-bottom {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
    transform: translateY(-100px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-bottom {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
    transform: translateY(-100px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.container {
  background-color: white;
}

.slide-bottom {
  z-index: -10;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    Stuff in container<br> Stuff in container<br> Stuff in container

    <div class="slide-bottom">
      <section class="section">
        <div class="container">
          <table class="table is-fullwidth">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Key 1</th>
                <th>Key 2</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Test</td>
                <td>Test</td>
                <td>Test</td>
                <td>Test</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>

    <nav class="pagination is-rounded" role="navigation" aria-label="pagination">
      <ul class="pagination-list">
        <li>
          <a class="pagination-link" class="is-current" aria-label="Page 1" aria-current="page">
            1
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="pagination-link" aria-label="Page 2" aria-current="page">
            2
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Why you need `.slide-bottom` to be `position: absolute`?

Comment: @MoshFeu If I don’t use `position: absolute`, the element will slide over the other content, not slide in below it.

Comment: If I understand you, you want the pagination will be below the table so it will slide below the table? I'm not sure I understand the effect you want to achieve..

Comment: @MoshFeu I want the pagination and the table to slide below the other content within the parent `.container` div.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you can move the nav into `.slide-bottom`, right?